# Displaying entity framework calls in Sequence Diagram

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sequence-diagram

I have a controller action which gets all the Plants by location from the database puts it inside a view model and passes it to the view.

```
public ActionResult index()
{
   List<Plant> plants = Context.Plant.ToList(data => data.location = "Canada");

   PlantsViewModel plantsViewModel = new PlantsViewModel
   {
      plant = plants
   };

   View(plants);
}
```

[image]

I would like to show this inside a sequence diagram. My problem comes when including the calls to entity framework which includes lambda expression, would it be consider too detailed to include the actual code (I am doing these diagrams after the code is complete just for documentation purposes) or should it be some sort of pseudocode in place of entity framework calls.

Comment: What is the purpose of this documentation? The appropriate content of any documentation is decided by its purpose.